# How to connect Zoho CRM api to Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, crm, zoho

I am trying to connect zoho crm api with flutter.  I am using oauth2client package from pub.dev.  How do I receive an access token after a use logs in with their zoho account?

[image]

[image: It also does not allow to add my app callback url. it required a https://]